# HashTable How to print repeated words only once?

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, hashtable

I'm implementing a hashTable, but I'm getting some problems, I print the updated hashtable always when a word is added, the problem is, when this word appears again I just need to increment its frequency, but my program is printing it again with the updated frequency: how can I print repeated words only once? And show their frequency.

The other problem I'm getting is in the function print_freq. It receives an int freq and I should print the words with this frequency, but the problem is that the auxTable is not saving the words from htable, I don't know why it's not working, because auxtable saves the frequency normal, but when it's going to save words it saves an empty char "".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define HTABLE_SIZE 1001
#define MAX_LINE_SIZ 1024

/* Hash Table */
typedef struct node* HASH_TABLE; /* estrutura de dados utilizadas para formar a hastable*/
struct node {
    char *palavra; /*word*/
    int freq;
};

/*Declaracao das funcoes*/
void inserirHashTable(char *s);
void print_ht();
void print_test();

HASH_TABLE htable[HTABLE_SIZE] = { NULL }; /* Hash table que armazenará as palavras lidas do arquivos */
unsigned int chaves[HTABLE_SIZE]; /* Vetor que armazenará as chaves das palavras da tabela*/
int tamanhoChaves=-1; /*Variavel responsavel por contar a quantidade de chaves do vetor de chaves*/
int size = 0; /* variavel responsavel por armazenar o numero de elementos da tabela*/

/*Função responsavel por processar o arquivo, a mesma recebe o arquivo como parametro,
 * pega cada palavra presente no arquivo separa dos simbolos ?!+.-... e chama a  função
 * inserirHT para inserir a palavra separada na tabela hash*/
void processarArquivo(FILE *fp)
{
    const char *seperators = " ?!'\";,.:+-*&%(){}[]<>\\\t\n"; // caractertes que deveram ser separados

    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZ];
    char *s;
    while((fgets(line,MAX_LINE_SIZ, fp)) != NULL) //pegando a linha do arquivo
    {
        for (s=strtok(line,seperators); s; s=strtok(NULL,seperators)){ // separando a palavra
            /*printf("Palavra a ser inserida %s \n",s); printf utilizado para mostrar
             * a palavra que foi seperada e será inserida*/
            inserirHashTable(s);//Chamando a função inserir
        }
    }
}

/* Função responsavel por criar a chave de cada palavra que vai para tabela,
  recebe como parametro um ponteiro para string, logo em seguida pega cada
  caractere da string e gera um unsigned int para ele, retorna por fim o
  modulo desse unsigned int pelo tamanho da tabela*/
unsigned int hash(char *tok)
{
    unsigned int hv = 0;
    while (*tok)
        hv = (hv << 4) | toupper(*tok++);
    /*printf("conversao: %d \n",hv); Printf utilizado para mostrar o valor de hv antes de ser retorna como modulo*/
    return hv % HTABLE_SIZE;
}

/* funcao responsavel por isenrir a palavra lida do arquivo na hash_table,
 * a funçãp recebe como parametro um ponteiro para estra palavra*/
void inserirHashTable(char *palavra) {
    /*printf("Inserindo a palavra %s \n",palavra); Printf utilzado para mostrar a palavra a ser inserida na tabela*/
    tamanhoChaves++; /*Assim que uma palavra é inserida o numero de chaves é incrementado*/
    chaves[tamanhoChaves] = hash(palavra);/*A palavra é convertida na função hash e sua armazenada no vetor de chaves*/
    unsigned int hashval = chaves[tamanhoChaves]; /*Chave da apalvra*/

    if (htable[hashval]==NULL){
      /*printf("indice %u de %s \n",hashval,palavra);Printf utilizado para mostrar a chave e a palavra a ser inserida*/
        htable[hashval] = malloc(sizeof(palavra)); /*Alocando memoria para palavrra*/
        htable[hashval]->palavra = palavra ; /*Inserindo a palavra*/
        htable[hashval]->freq = 1; /*Incrementado sua frequencia*/
        size++;

    }else {
        /*If a words already exists in the table, i just incremente her frequency and the size. I guess the problem for repeated word is in here*/
        htable[hashval]->freq++;
        size++;
    }
    /*A tabela é impressa a cada instante que uma palavra é inserida*/
    printf("\nAtualização da tabela\n");
    print_ht();/*Impressao das palavras já recebidas, a cada instante, com a quantidade de ocorrências*/

}


/* Function responsible to print the words that were addedd to the hash table*/
void print_ht() {
    int i=0;
    /*Tabela auxiliar que servira para impressao das palavras e suas chaves*/
    HASH_TABLE *auxTable = (HASH_TABLE*) malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE)*size);
    unsigned int hashval; /* variavel utilizada para pegar a chave das palavras no vetor de chaves */

    for(i; i < size; i++){
        hashval = chaves[i]; /*Pegando a chave*/
        /*printf("indice %u de %s \n",hashval,htable[hashval]->token);Printf utilizado para ver a chave e a palavra*/
        auxTable[i] = htable[hashval]; /*Atribuindo a palavra e a freq para tabela auxiliar*/
    }

    /*qsort(auxTable,size,sizeof(link),compare);*/
    /*Imprimindo a tabela*/
    printf("Palavra  |  Frequencia\n");
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s  \t        %d\n",auxTable[i]->palavra,auxTable[i]->freq);
    free(auxTable);
}

/*Funcion responsible to print the words with the frequency received in the paramater*/
void print_freq(int freq){
    printf("Palavras com a frequencia: %d\n", freq);
    int i, j =0;
    HASH_TABLE *auxTable = (HASH_TABLE*) malloc(sizeof(HASH_TABLE)*size);
    unsigned int hashval;

    for(i; i < size; i++){
        hashval = chaves[i];
        /*printf("indice %u de %s \n",hashval,htable[hashval]->palavra);*/
        auxTable[i] = htable[hashval]; /*Problem is in here, when I do this, the auxTable[i]->palavra(word) = "", but the freq has been saved normally n*/
    }

    printf("Palavra  |  Frequencia\n");
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if(auxTable[i]->freq == freq) {
            printf("%s  \t           %d\n",auxTable[i]->palavra,auxTable[i]->freq); /*When I print, only the frequency is showed*/
        }
    }
    free(auxTable);

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error ao abrir o arquivo: %s\n",fp);
    }
    printf("Imprimindo processo \n");
    processarArquivo(fp); /* debuuga aqui pra tu entender o q rola*/

    fclose(fp);
    print_freq(3); //should print the word with freq equal to 3
    //print_ht();
    /*clear_ht();*/
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/PlRPp]

Comment: You don't actually scan through the hash table; you scan through the `chaves[]` array, which contains the hash value of each word you've encountered in the order you encounter them. You don't need the aux table either; a simple `for (hashval = 0; hashval < HTABLE_SIZE; h++) if (htable[hashval] != NULL) printf("%s \t %d\n", htable[hashval]->palavra, htable[hashval]->freq);` should suffice.

Comment: Unfortunately, you also have a fundamental bug: If two words hash to the same value, you treat them as the same word. This is called a *[hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)*, and there are several different ways to solve it. My favourite is to make the nodes into singly-linked lists. (By the way, it's very hard to read code written in mixed languages. I'm not a native English speaker myself. The C keywords are already in English, so it's easier for others to read/help when all the code and comments are in English, and English only.)

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I'm sorry for this shitting comments, all of then are in portugues --', btw, thats my problem, i don't how to treat hash colisions, do you have any material or code for this?

Comment: @JacekŚlimok: Hey, you stole that link from my comment! (Just kidding!) :)

Comment: Thank you guys, This is just a homework of Data Structure discipline from college, I'm going to hide the collisions haha, but I'm gonna read this link to learn this shit for future codes

Comment: @NominalAnimal Oh, now I've noticed. Removed my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd solve the collisions, and also allow resizing the hash table if/when necessary without rehashing all the words.

First, I'd use a singly-linked list to contain all the different words that have the same hash. I'd also save the hash -- full hash, not modulo hash table size -- to allow easy resizing of the hash table. Finally, I like to use the C99 *flexible array member* for the word itself:

```
struct hash_entry {
    struct hash_entry  *next;   /* Pointer to next word in this hash table entry */
    size_t              hash;   /* Any unsigned type works; I just like size_t */
    size_t              freq;   /* Frequency */
    char                word[]; /* C99 flexible array member */
};
```

A hash table is just an array of `size` pointers, with each word that hashes to `hash` being in the singly-linked list hanging off `entry[hash % size]`:

```
struct hash_table {
    size_t              size;
    struct hash_entry **entry;
};
```

The basic functions to initialize, resize, and free a hash table are then

```
int hash_table_create(struct hash_table *ht, size_t size)
{
    size_t  i;

    if (ht == NULL || size < 1)
        return -1; /* Invalid parameters */

    ht->size = size;
    ht->entry = malloc(size * sizeof ht->entry[0]);
    if (ht->entry == NULL)
        return -2; /* Cannot allocate memory */

    /* Clear all entries: no hashes/chains yet! */
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)        
        ht->entry[i] = NULL;

    return 0; /* Success, no errors. */
}

void hash_entry_free(struct hash_entry *entry)
{
    while (entry) {
        struct hash_entry *next = entry->next;

        /* I like to "poison" the freed entries;
           this makes debugging easier, if you try
           to access an already freed entry. */
        entry->hash = 0;
        entry->freq = 0;
        entry->next = NULL;

        free(entry);

        entry = next;
    }
}

void hash_table_free(struct hash_table *ht)
{
    if (ht != NULL) {
        size_t  i;

        for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++)
            if (ht->entry[i] != NULL)
                hash_entry_free(ht->entry[i]);

        free(ht->entry);

        ht->size = 0;
        ht->entry = NULL;
    }
}

int hash_table_resize(struct hash_table *ht, size_t new_size)
{
    struct hash_entry **entry;
    struct hash_entry  *curr, *next; 
    size_t  i, k;

    if (!ht || new_size < 1)
        return -1; /* Invalid parameters */

    if (ht->size < 1 || !ht->entry)
        return -2; /* Hash table is already freed */

    entry = malloc(new_size * sizeof entry[0]);
    if (!entry)
        return -3; /* Not enough memory */

    for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
        entry[i] = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {

        /* Chain in the old hash table entry */
        curr = ht->entry[i];            

        /* We are paranoid, and clear the old entry. */
        ht->entry[i] = NULL;

        while (curr) {
            /* Remember next hash in this chain */
            next = curr->next;

            /* Index to the new hash table */
            k = curr->hash % new_size;

            /* Prepend in front of the new hash table entry chain */
            curr->next = entry[k];
            entry[k] = curr;

            /* Advance to the next entry in the old chain */
            curr = next;
        }

    /* The old table is now useless. Free it, and use the new one. */
    free(ht->entry);
    ht->entry = entry;
    ht->size = new_size;

    return 0; /* Success; no errors. */
}
```

As to hash functions, I do like the [djb2 xor hash](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html):

```
size_t hash(const char *s)
{
    if (s != NULL) {
        size_t  result = 5381;

        while (*s != '\0')
            result = (result * 33) ^ (*(s++));

        return result;
    } else
        return 0;
}

size_t hash_len(const char *s, const size_t len)
{
    if (s != NULL) {
        const char *z = s + len;
        size_t  result = 5381;

        while (s < z)
            result = (result * 33) ^ (*(s++));

        return result;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

I'd also split adding a string/word to the hash table into two functions: first function creates the `struct hash_entry` and copies the source word into it, and the second function uses the first one to create the entry, and then just adds it to the hash table:

```
struct hash_entry *hash_entry_new_len(const char *src, size_t len)
{
    struct hash_entry *h;

    if (len > 0 && !src)
       return NULL; /* NULL src, but positive len! */

    /* To accommodate the flexible array member, we need
       to add its size to the structure size. Since it
       is a string, we need to include room for the '\0'. */
    h = malloc(sizeof (struct hash_entry) + len + 1);
    if (!h)
        return NULL; /* Out of memory */

    /* Copy the string to the entry, */
    if (len > 0)
        memcpy(h->word, src, len);

    /* Add the string-terminating nul char, */
    h->word[len] = '\0';

    /* clear the next pointer, */
    h->next = NULL;

    /* set the frequency count to 1, */
    h->freq = 1;

    /* and compute the hash. */
    h->hash = hash_len(src, len);

    /* Done! */
    return h;
}

struct hash_entry *hash_entry_new(const char *src)
{
    const size_t  len = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    return hash_entry_new_len(src, len);
}

struct hash_entry *hash_table_add_part(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src, const size_t len)
{
    struct hash_entry *h;
    size_t             k;

    if (!ht || ht->size < 1)
        return NULL;  /* No hash table! */

    /* We'll check src and len, so we report the right error. */
    if (!src && len > 0)
        return NULL;  /* Invalid src (NULL)! */

    h = hash_entry_new(src, len);
    if (!h)
        return NULL;  /* Must be out of memory! */

    /* Index into the hash table */
    k = h->hash % ht->size;

    /* Prepend new hash table entry to the beginning of the chain. */
    h->next = ht->entry[k];
    ht->entry[k] = h;

    /* Success! */
    return h;
}

/* Helper function, so you don't need to specify the length
   if you wish to add a copy of entire source string. */
struct hash_entry *hash_table_add(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src)
{
    const size_t  len = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    return hash_table_add_part(ht, src, len);
}
```

The `len = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0` expression is shorthand for `if (src != NULL) len = strlen(src); else len = 0;`. I use it a lot, as a safe way to check string length, or use 0 if the string is empty or NULL.

Also note that a NULL string will receive hash `0`, whereas an empty string will hash to `5381`. It's not important, I just like to dot the i's that way (or be utterly and overly nitpicky and full of hot air, like they say).

Note that my "normal" functions end with `_len()`, with the functions with the same name but without the `_len()` suffix are helper functions that use the entire string.  This is useful, if you do not use `strtok()` to split the string, but e.g. `strspn()`/`strcspn()` or even regular expressions to find the interesting words in each string.

To find a specific word in the hash table, we need to have the original string to compare to; the hash itself is not sufficient:

```
struct hash_entry *hash_table_find_len(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src, const size_t len)
{
    const size_t  hashval = hash_len(src, len);
    struct hash_entry *curr = ht->entry[hashval % ht->size];

    /* No matches for sure? */
    if (!curr)
        return NULL;

    /* We have a chain (singly-linked list).
       Check each one in turn. */
    while (curr) {

       /* Since we kept the entire hash value,
          and not just the index to the hash table,
          we can use the extra bits to exclude
          words that have the same hash modulus (index)
          but different complete hash value! */
       if (curr->hash == hash) {

           /* We cannot use strncmp() if len == 0,
              so we check that case separately. */
           if (len == 0) {
               if (curr->word[0] == '\0')
                   return curr; /* Match found! */
           } else {
               if (!strncmp(curr->word, src, len) &&
                   curr->word[len] == '\0')
                   return curr; /* Match found! */
           }
       }

       /* No match. Check next one in chain. */
       curr = curr->next;
    }

    /* Nope, no match. */
    return NULL;
}

struct hash_entry *hash_table_find(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src)
{
    const size_t  len = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    return hash_table_find_len(ht, src, len);
}
```

Counting the frequency of words is now simple:

```
int hash_table_seen_len(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src, const size_t len)
{
    struct hash_entry *h;

    /* Sanity checks first. */
    if (!ht || (!src && len > 0))
        return -1; /* Invalid parameters! */

    h = hash_table_find_len(ht, src, len);
    if (h) {
        /* Found match; increment freq counter. */
        h->freq++;
        /* All done. */
        return 0;
    }

    /* Not found. Add to hash table. */
    h = hash_table_add_len(ht, src, len);
    if (!h) {
        /* An error occurred; should be "out of memory",
           since we checked the other causes earlier
           in this function. */
        return -1;
    }

    /* The word was added to the hash table.
       Since its freq count is 1, we do not need
       to increment it; we're done. */
    return 0;
}

int hash_table_seen(struct hash_table *ht, const char *src)
{
    const size_t  len = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    return hash_table_seen_len(ht, src, len);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that to print the hash table entries in order of frequency, I'd use two helper functions: one to find the largest frequency, and the other to find the largest frequency less than a given frequency:

```
size_t hash_table_max_freq(struct hash_table *ht)
{
    size_t  result = 0;
    size_t  i;

    if (!ht || ht->size < 1)
        return 0;  /* No hash table. */

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
        struct hash_entry *curr = ht->entry[i];

        while (curr) {
            if (curr->freq > result)
                result = curr->freq;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

size_t hash_table_next_freq(struct hash_table *ht, const size_t max_freq)
{
    size_t  result = 0;
    size_t  i;

    if (!ht || ht->size < 1)
        return 0;  /* No hash table. */

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
        struct hash_entry *curr = ht->entry[i];

        while (curr) {
            if (curr->freq > result && curr->freq < max_freq)
                result = curr->freq;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Finally, we can "steal" the interface of `qsort()` to find all words, or all words with a specific frequency:

```
int hash_table_for_all(struct hash_table *ht,
                       int (*func)(struct hash_entry *, void *),
                       void *user_data)
{
    int     retval;
    size_t  i;

    if (!ht || !func)
        return -1; /* NULL hash table or function. */

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
        struct hash_entry *curr = ht->entry[i];
        while (curr) {
            retval = func(curr, user_data);
            if (retval)
                return retval;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int hash_table_for_freq(struct hash_table *ht, const size_t freq,
                       int (*func)(struct hash_entry *, void *),
                       void *user_data)
{
    int     retval;
    size_t  i;

    if (!ht || !func)
        return -1; /* NULL hash table or function. */

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
        struct hash_entry *curr = ht->entry[i];
        while (curr) {
            if (curr->freq == freq) {
                retval = func(curr, user_data);
                if (retval)
                    return retval;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

None of the above code is even compile-tested, so if you find any typos (or run into compile-time errors), please let me know in a comment so I can verify and fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what you're storing as `node.palavra`. If we trace it it's the input of `inserirHashTable` which in turn is the result of calling `strtok` in `processarArquivo`. This is where things get hairy as said pointer is within the input array which is a local variable `line` within function `processarArquivo`. This will get invalid once you scan another line from file or terminate this function. This is exactly the reason this works just fine while constructing hash table (`processarArquivo` and `line` is still in scope) and results in undefined behaviour once the function terminate (when you return to `main` and proceed to call `print_freq`).

Now, there are 2 points to improve in `inserirHashTable`:

- Notice how you call [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). You allocate sizeof(char*) bytes to hold a new HASH_TABLE structure. Why?
- what's more, you're copying the pointer as a value of `palavra` field. You should [make a copy here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938813/7034621).

Bonus issues are uninitialized `i` variable in print_freq, the existence of `auxTable` and the fact that you assume the value of hash is unique which is wrong (how could it be? there are more than 1001 distinct words!).

Comment: Oh shit, so all of my problems is in the processarArquivo? You know a way that I can read the file and send the words to inserirHastTable different than that? '

Comment: @RafaelCamara I would suggest linked way of making string's copy. The way you read files seem fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I did your exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//hash table size
#define SIZE 1000
//maximum size of the input string
#define STR_LEN 100

typedef struct linked_list {
    unsigned char value[STR_LEN];
    unsigned int cnt;   
    struct linked_list *next;
} linked_list;

void print_items(int freq); 
void print_freq(int freq);
void print_table();
int add_to_table(unsigned char *str); 
unsigned long get_hash(unsigned char *str);

linked_list* table[SIZE];

int main() {
    unsigned char str[STR_LEN];
    //the fgets function allows the spaces in the string.
    //so, strings like: 'red green blue' are possible.
    while(fgets(str, STR_LEN, stdin)) {
        sscanf(str, "%[^\n]", str);

        add_to_table(str);
    }

    print_freq(2);

    return 0;
}

void print_table(){
    puts("Whole table");
    print_items(0);
}

void print_freq(int freq){
    printf("Words with frequency: %d\n", freq);
    print_items(freq);
}

// if freq = 0, it prints all hash table items.
// if freq = 1, 2, 3... it prints only items with the specific frequency.
void print_items(int freq) {
    int i;
    linked_list *node;
    puts("----------------------");
    puts("Values\t|  Frequency");
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        node = table[i];
        while(node) {
            if(freq && freq != node->cnt) {
                node = node->next;
                continue;
            }
            printf("%s\t|  %d\n", node->value, node->cnt);
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    puts("----------------------");
}

//Collision processing implemented by the linked list.
//In the beginning, all items of the hash table are NULL.
//
//The first string with specific hash goes to the corresponding 'table' array index
//in the linked list's node form.
//
//Then, if the collision occurs (different string with the same hash)
//the new node shifts the previous node and linking to it 
int add_to_table(unsigned char *str) {
        unsigned long hash;
        hash = get_hash(str);
        hash = hash & SIZE;

        linked_list *node = table[hash];

        while(node) {
            if(strcmp(str, node->value) == 0) {
                node->cnt++;    
                return 1;
            }
            node = node->next;
        }

        //if the item does not exist (wasn't found in the previous while loop),
        //the new node is created
        linked_list *new_node = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        //the new node 'next' field is pointing to the previous 
        //first node (head) of the linked list
        new_node->next = table[hash];
        new_node->cnt = 1;
        strcpy(new_node->value, str);

        //and the new node became the new 'head'
        table[hash] = new_node; 

        print_table();

        return 1;
}

// the 'djb2' hash algorithm is used
unsigned long get_hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str) {
        hash = hash * 33 + c;
        str++;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

**Testing:**

```
one                          <--- input "one"
Whole table                  <--- output 
----------------------            the whole table is printed each time,
Values  |  Frequency              the new string is added
one     |  1
----------------------
two                          <--- input "two"
Whole table
----------------------
Values  |  Frequency
two     |  1
one     |  1
----------------------
one                          <--- input - no output, because the hash table 
                                  already have this string
two                          <--- input - the same
three                        <--- input - the output is appearing now,
                                  'three' didn't inputted before
Whole table
----------------------
Values  |  Frequency
two     |  2
three   |  1
one     |  2
----------------------
Words with frequency: 2      <--- I am send EOF (end of file) to the
                                  program by Ctrl-D 
----------------------
Values  |  Frequency          
two     |  2
one     |  2
----------------------
```